# There is no link to go to Stack Exchange homepage from within Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-exchange

If you are inside Stack Overflow there is no link to go to the Stack Exchange main page (https://stackexchange.com/). When you click on the Stack Exchange icon it just shows a dropdown list, and on that dropdown Stack Exchange is not even listed (they are all listed, Super User, Server Fault, etc., *except* Stack Exchange).

Comment: All the other sites are like that too (I think)

Comment: There's a link to your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/6923457/gabriel-rodriguez) in your [profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5315239/gabriel-rodriguez?tab=profile), below the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: Scroll down a bit, and click on the "Hot Network Questions"

Comment: Ok @Bjom don't you think that is too slow?, you have to navigate to another page first and then click on that link?...(is misleading for the final user)....and it doesn't even takes you to the StackExchange Homepage

Comment: @CoolGuy I don't see that option you mention, and if it is there, there is no way to know for the final user that "Hot Questions" is StackExchange Homepage anyway

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez Sorry. Forgot to mention that it isn't in the drop-down list, but in the page. You'll see "Hot Network Questions" in the right sidebar of this page after scrolling down a bit.

Comment: ok @CoolGuy I found it and it does takes you to the Homepage. But anyway, for the final user there is no way to know that.

Answer (score 2):

If you middle click (or right click and select to open the link) on the Stack Exchange Menu, it will open a link to https://stackexchange.com/.

[image: Stack Exchange Menu]

*Middle click on this icon*

Comment: middle click doesn't works, I tried it, and its not my mouse, I tried it with other links and it does works...so the problem is exactly on that icon. Also what about if you are on a laptop? you don't have middle click

Comment: And the second option you mention(the right click->new tab) is not user friendly either because it is not just StackOverflow, it is from all other sites also that this option is not available...so do you think that all of those other  StackExchange users(economics, history, law) know that there is even a right-click-new-tab option? I don't think so....That's only us, tech people.

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez Then you have 2 options... Umm use the URL bar? Add a bookmark? Also on a laptop, you can often press both left and right at the same time to middle click.

Comment: @Tim I already knew that before asking the question....I'm just talking about the site navigation for the final user. Look, the link to StackExchange Home is already there on the top icon(if you look at your Browser status bar when you hover on it)...is just it doesn't works!...Its like they've overridden the onClick event with JavaScript.

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez Try CTRL + left mouse click instead of middle click.

Comment: @CoolGuy nope, that CTRL+ Left click does not works here. Does it works on your machine...Im using Chrome ...you?

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez I don't know if it works as I'm using my phone now. However, holding on the "StackExhange" on Chrome on Android gives the option to open http://www.stackexchange.com in a new tab, new window etc

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez Try dragging the "_Stack Exchange_" onto the tab list.

Answer (score 1):

There are many links that get you in the right ballpark: legal/privacy policy/advertising info in the footer, "more stack exchange communities" and "your communities" in the site switcher.

stackexchange.com itself isn't a Q&A site. It's a portal that (historically speaking) is designed to give someone an overview of the company and people's network profiles. When someone is visiting a particular site, we try to focus on that site instead, with the site switcher and the site footer there to provide some awareness of the overall "network".

We also recently [rebranded back to Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/), so some of the company-related links may be moving around in the near future.

All in all, this is currently by design. What in particular about stackexchange.com makes you wish we had a more direct link to it?

Comment: Ok, just answer me this, Why if the link is already there, it doesn't works as it should?...That's the only thing I don't understand.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work as it should"? The link in the image is just a fall-back for people who don't have JavaScript enabled.